# Create a column removing unwanted parts of strings based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, split

I'm new to python and I'm stuck here. I have a dataframe like the one below and I'm trying to create a new column with only the macro genres of the Genres column.

Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Genres': ['Finance', 'Arcade', 'Business', 'Photography', 'Entertainment;Brain Games', 'Medical', 'Tools', 'Casual;Brain Games', 'Medical', 'Entertainment'], 
     'Last Updated': ['March 10, 2018', 'May 24, 2018', 'April 11, 2018', 'November 6, 2014', 'March 9, 2018', 'May 17, 2018', 'June 3, 2016', 'April 10, 2016', 'July 16, 2018', 'May 17, 2017']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

                       Genres        Last Updated
0                     Finance      March 10, 2018
1                      Arcade        May 24, 2018
2                    Business      April 11, 2018
3                 Photography    November 6, 2014
4   Entertainment;Brain Games       March 9, 2018
5                     Medical        May 17, 2018
6                       Tools        June 3, 2016
7          Casual;Brain Games      April 10, 2016
8                     Medical       July 16, 2018
9               Entertainment        May 17, 2017
```

The desired output would be something like:

```
                       Genres          macro_genres        Last Updated
0                     Finance               Finance      March 10, 2018
1                      Arcade                Arcade        May 24, 2018
2                    Business              Business      April 11, 2018
3                 Photography           Photography    November 6, 2014
4   Entertainment;Brain Games         Entertainment       March 9, 2018
5                     Medical               Medical        May 17, 2018
6                       Tools                 Tools        June 3, 2016
7          Casual;Brain Games                Casual      April 10, 2016
8                     Medical               Medical       July 16, 2018
9               Entertainment         Entertainment        May 17, 2017
```

What I have tried:

```
def macro_genre(i):
    for i in df['Genres']:
        if ';' in i:
            j = i.split(';')[0]
            return j
        else:
            return i
                    
df['macro_genres'] = df['Genres'].apply(macro_genre)
```

But it is not working. It creates the column, but it repeats the first value for the whole column.

When I try the `for` part outside the function, it works.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm new here. Which part do you say should be minimal reproducible, the dataframe itself? I typed it because it's just a small part of a larger dataframe.

Comment: _Which part do you say should be minimal reproducible, the dataframe itself?_ It should be possible to copy/paste your code and data and be able to run the code practically immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the tip AMC. Although the solution was already given, I have included the code to generate the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility could be to use `map`:

```
df['macro_games'] = df['Genres'].astype(str).map(lambda x : x.split(';')[0])
```

**Output**:

```
>>> df
                       Genres          macro_genres        Last Updated
0                     Finance               Finance      March 10, 2018
1                      Arcade                Arcade        May 24, 2018
2                    Business              Business      April 11, 2018
3                 Photography           Photography    November 6, 2014
4   Entertainment;Brain Games         Entertainment       March 9, 2018
5                     Medical               Medical        May 17, 2018
6                       Tools                 Tools        June 3, 2016
7          Casual;Brain Games                Casual      April 10, 2016
8                     Medical               Medical       July 16, 2018
9               Entertainment         Entertainment        May 17, 2017
```

**Runtime Comparision on 1k dataframe:**

```
#apply method
>>> %timeit -n 1000 df['Genres'].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0])
535 µs ± 12.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#str split method (slowest)
>>> %timeit -n 1000 df['Genres'].str.split(';').str[0]
1.36 ms ± 44.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#map method
>>> %timeit -n 1000 df['Genres'].map(lambda x : x.split(';')[0])
527 µs ± 17.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Runtime Comparision on 10k dataframe:**

```
#apply method
>>> %timeit -n 1000 df['Genres'].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0])
3.62 ms ± 105 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#str split method (slowest)
>>> %timeit -n 1000 df['Genres'].str.split(';').str[0]
10 ms ± 259 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#map method
>>> %timeit -n 1000 df['Genres'].map(lambda x : x.split(';')[0])
3.47 ms ± 59.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Runtime Comparision on 50k dataframe:**

```
#apply method
>>> %timeit -n 1000 df['Genres'].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0])
17 ms ± 133 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#map method 
>>> %timeit -n 1000 df['Genres'].map(lambda x : x.split(';')[0])
16.7 ms ± 278 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Runtime Comparision on 100k dataframe:**

```
#apply method
>>> %timeit -n 1000 df['Genres'].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0])
34.1 ms ± 1.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#map method 
>>> %timeit -n 1000 df['Genres'].astype(str).map(lambda x : x.split(';')[0])
35.5 ms ± 596 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Upvoted for the benchmark. It would be nice to see comparisons for dataframes of different lengths.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks for the upvote. Updated my answer with 1K,10K,50K,100K dataframes. I retract my statement that `map` is faster. It is marginally better on small dfs, however, seems to become slower on large dfs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Grayrigel! I was sure there was a clean and easy solution, but was not getting there. It totally worked!

Comment: Does the speed matter? Wouldn't it be better to use the cleaner/more idiomatic method?

Comment: @AMC I think speed matters, especially if you are dealing with large dataframes. I am not sure what could be better than half line of code. What do you suggest? Do you have an alternate method?

Comment: @Grayrigel I'm trying some benchmarks now. How did you make the datasets in yours? The proportion of rows that contain a semi-colon, and the number of semi-colons in each one, should have a decent impact on the benchmarks, right?

Comment: Sure. It can have an impact. Perhaps you can duplicate. I used `df.sample( 100000, replace=True, random_state=27)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `str.split(';')`. If `;` is not present in string, nothing happens -> the list with original string is returned (so you can always use `[0]`):

```
df['macro_genres'] = df['Genres'].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                      Genres      Last_Updated   macro_genres
0                    Finance    March 10, 2018        Finance
1                     Arcade      May 24, 2018         Arcade
2                   Business    April 11, 2018       Business
3                Photography  November 6, 2014    Photography
4  Entertainment;Brain_Games     March 9, 2018  Entertainment
5                    Medical      May 17, 2018        Medical
6                      Tools      June 3, 2016          Tools
7         Casual;Brain Games    April 10, 2016         Casual
8                    Medical     July 16, 2018        Medical
9              Entertainment      May 17, 2017  Entertainment
```

Comment: I was going to say `df['macro_genres'] = df['Genres'].str.split(';').str[0]` might be a better answer, but the performance is better with your answer with a quick `%timeit`.  It is `258 µs` vs. `474 µs`.

Comment: @DavidErickson Why not use `map`. I think it is faster than apply. See my answer runtime comparison on a 10k dataframe.

Comment: @grayrigel I don’t think you’ll see a big performance difference between apply and map for this purpose as shown in your answer.

Comment: @DavidErickson Yes. you are right. I did a test on various lengths. I retract my  statement that `map` is faster. It is marginally better on small dfs, however, seems to become slower on large dfs.